# Mysql and PHP UNIQUE error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code which works fine but the thing is that in my database, cupon is UNIQUE and the code just doesn't show me any error. Why is that or how do I make it to show?

```
mysqli_query($link, "BEGIN");
$ins_cupon = mysqli_query($link, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$ruta."' INTO TABLE cupones FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE ".$lines." LINES (@col1, @col2) SET encuesta_id = '".$encuesta_id."', nom_producto = '".$nombre_producto."', cupon = @col2") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$upd_cupon = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE cupones SET cupon = REPLACE(cupon, CHAR(13), '') WHERE encuesta_id = '".$encuesta_id."'") or die(mysqli_error($link));;

if($ins_cupon && $upd_cupon){
    mysqli_query($link, "COMMIT");
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}else{
    mysqli_query($link, "ROLLBACK");
    $error = "No se pudo completar la operación";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: What exactly is the question?  You say your code works fine, so why are you expecting an error?

Comment: Because cupon is UNIQUE and when I insert the same value this doesn't insert but the code doesn'0t show me any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LOCAL` keyword is likely the "culprit" here, so to speak.  According to the [`LOAD DATA` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

> With LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, data-interpretation and duplicate-key
>   errors become warnings and the operation continues because the server
>   has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the
>   operation. For duplicate-key errors, this is the same as if IGNORE is
>   specified. IGNORE is explained further later in this section.

So even though you are not explicitly using the `IGNORE` keyword, it's as if you are.

Comment: The IGNORE in this case is for ingore N number of lines because i'm loading data from a file

Comment: @Polo Ah, my bad.  I took a quick scan and saw `IGNORE` and didn't pay attention to where it was.

Comment: @Polo I revised my answer.  It still comes down to the duplicate-key errors being ignored, just not because of an explicit use of `IGNORE`.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why but I've solved my problem using fgetcsv

Comment: My answer explains exactly why.  It's the known and expected behavior of `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

To show errors write on top of your script

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

this should let you see the errors

Edit: If you haven't got any error, this won't show you anything

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem using fgetcsv

```
    $nd_column = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($ruta, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        fgetcsv($handle);
        mysqli_query($link, "BEGIN");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {

            $ins_cupon = mysqli_query ($link, "INSERT INTO cupones (encuesta_id, nom_producto, cupon) VALUES ('".$encuesta_id."', '".$nombre_producto."', '".$data[$nd_column]."')") or die(mysqli_error($link));

        }
        fclose($handle);                
    }

    if($ins_cupon){
        mysqli_query($link, "COMMIT");
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        mysqli_query($link, "ROLLBACK");
        $error = "No se pudo completar la operación";
        exit();
    }
```